Videojs 8 player mp4 not passing jwt token
I am developing a videojs player using react, typescript. But I can't get the video. It says unauthorized.
I already tried using vanilla way (without videojs) and it is working. I will state both tries below.
My versions:
video.js: "8.21.0",
@types/video.js: "7.3.58",
react: 18.3.1
// VideoPlayerMP4.tsx
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import videojs from 'video.js';
import Player from 'video.js/dist/types/player';
import 'video.js/dist/video-js.css';

type PlayerOptions = typeof videojs.options;

interface VideoPlayerProps {
  id?: string;
  url?: string;
  options?: PlayerOptions;
  styles?: string;
  jwtToken: string;
}

const VideoPlayerMP4: React.FC<VideoPlayerProps> = ({
  url,
  options,
  styles,
  jwtToken,
}: VideoPlayerProps) => {
  const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement | null>(null);
  const playerRef = useRef<Player | null>();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!options.sources.length || !videoRef.current) return;

    const customOptions: PlayerOptions = {
      ...options,
      html5: {
        xhr: {
          before: (xhr: XMLHttpRequest) => {
            console.log('sent video token'); // i don't see this log
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${jwtToken}`);
          },
        },
      },
    };

    console.log('sources', options);

    if (!playerRef.current) {
      const player = videojs(videoRef.current, customOptions, () => {
        console.log('Video player is ready');
      });

      playerRef.current = player;

      player.on('error', () => {});

      player.on('loadedmetadata', () => {});

      player.on('playing', () => {});
    } else {
      const currentSrc = playerRef.current.currentSrc();
      const newSrc = customOptions.sources[0].src;
      const player = playerRef.current;

      if (currentSrc !== newSrc) {
        player.autoplay(customOptions.autoplay);
        player.src(customOptions.sources);
      }
    }
  }, [url, options, jwtToken]);

  return (
    <div className={styles}>
      <video
        ref={videoRef}
        className="video-js vjs-theme-city vjs-big-play-centered"
        style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
      ></video>
    </div>
  );
};

export default VideoPlayerMP4;

// VideoPlayerVinilla.tsx
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

interface VideoPlayerProps {
  videoUrl: string;
  jwtToken: string;
  className?: string;
}

const VideoPlayerVanilla: React.FC<VideoPlayerProps> = ({
  videoUrl,
  jwtToken,
  className,
}) => {
  const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const attachStream = () => {
      if (!videoRef.current) return;

      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET', videoUrl, true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${jwtToken}`);
      xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

      xhr.onload = () => {
        if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
          const videoBlob = new Blob([xhr.response], { type: 'video/mp4' });
          const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(videoBlob);

          videoRef.current!.src = blobUrl;
        } else {
          console.error('Failed to load video:', xhr.statusText);
        }
      };

      xhr.onerror = () => {
        console.error('An error occurred during the video request');
      };

      xhr.send();
    };

    attachStream();

    return () => {
      // Revoke blob URL if used
      if (videoRef.current) {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(videoRef.current.src);
        videoRef.current.src = '';
      }
    };
  }, [videoUrl, jwtToken]);

  return (
    <div className={className}>
      <video
        ref={videoRef}
        controls
        autoPlay
        style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
      >
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
    </div>
  );
};

export default VideoPlayerVanilla;


Usage
<VideoPlayeMP4
              url={videoDetails?.video_url || ''}
              jwtToken={token}
              options={{
                autoplay: true,
                controls: true,
                muted: false,
                preload: 'auto',
                aspectRatio: '16:9',
                fluid: true,
                responsive: true,
                poster: null,
                sources: [
                  {
                    src: videoDetails?.video_url || '',
                    type: 'video/mp4',
                  },
                ],
              }}
            />

<VideoPlayerVanilla
    videoUrl={videoDetails?.video_url || ''}
    jwtToken={token}
    className="video-container"
/>


First, Add console.log('customOptions:', customOptions) to verify the options passed to video.js
Second, Update video.js:
const customOptions: PlayerOptions = {
  ...options,
  html5: {
    ...options.html5,
    hls: {
      overrideNative: true, // Ensure the native behavior is overridden
    },
    xhr: {
      beforeSend: (xhr: XMLHttpRequest) => {
        console.log('Setting Authorization header');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${jwtToken}`);
      },
    },
  },
};

maybe that will be helpful!

i see custom options printed out correctly. also updated like your answer. didn't work.

cool, add console.log('BeforeSend triggered'); in the xhr.beforeSend function. If this isn't logged, the xhr.beforeSend method isn't being called, indicating that the problem is with the way the browser or video.js processes the request.
